# My shopping cart works randomly when moving to different pages

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, session, cookie, .htaccess

I've spent hours and days trying to fix it but I can't figure out why when I move from one page to another my cart changes.
First of all I add a product to the cart. The cart updates itself and I can see that product on the cart. But when I click on home it switches to 0 products for no reason. A part from this, when switching to a category page it doesn't show 0 or 1 product, it shows me the products I added a couple days ago.
I have set the cookie management to 3600. I wonder if it is related to my .htaccess, which I took from internet to have a fast magento website. This is the piece of code from my .htaccess related to session:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c> 
    php_value memory_limit 512M 
    php_value max_execution_time 18000 
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off 
    php_flag session.auto_start off 
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off 
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off 
</IfModule>
```

It's interesting the fact that I've recently made another website with Magento 1.9.2 and same think happens. The only Magento where it works is a localhost copy, it's kinda frustrating.
Why is this happening?
**EDIT:**
This is what I have in my htaccess related to caching.

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
</ifModule>
```

And

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 weeks"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 weeks"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 weeks"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 weeks"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 weeks"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 days"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 2 days"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 2 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 2 days"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 2 days"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 days"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 weeks"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using any full page cache? It sounds like the behaviour of a cache. For example, it says 0 on the homepage but the item is still in the cart if you goto checkout? This would mean your cart block is being cached on the homepage and you need to 'hole punch' or 'bypass' the cart block (only if you're using some kind of cache, though)

Comment: Yes, the item remains when going to checkout. I edit my question to show what I have in my .htaccess related to caching.

Comment: Can you try removing the entire <IfModule mod_expires.c> block and see if the issue still occurs? To get a decent performance gain out of magento you want to be using full page caching, Lesti_Fpc is a good free one to start with. https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc

Comment: I have this installed as well

Comment: Make sure you have set the bypass handle in system -> lesti fpc -> dynamic blocks. For instance mine is named 'topcart' in my theme, so I put the cart here. You should also disable the module and see if the problem still occurs, then you'll know if it's the FPC or not

Comment: I've tried by removing <IfModule mod_expires.c> and after cleaning cache and cookies the problem persists. May I have to change something from Lesti_Fpc? Someone recommended me to add it (in both websites) but I just installed it without modifying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've configured your Lesti_Fpc blocks correctly - please see 
https://gordonlesti.com/what-are-lazy-and-dynamic-blocks-in-lestifpc/

Make sure you have set the bypass handle in admin

```
system -> lesti fpc -> dynamic blocks
```

For instance mine is named 'topcart' in my theme, so I put the text topcart in the dynamic blocks field.

Comment: I finally found the name my minicart had. In my case it was 'top_cart'. Just added where you said and it works perfect now. Thank you very much!